# #include .h or .cpp file?

Tags: c++

So I have this weird looking problem: my very basic program generates an error message (undefined reference to 'foo::foo(int)') when i import the .h file of a separate class. However, when I change the import file to .cpp, it all works.

Now, I've read a little, and seen a few video tutorials, and they all say the same: import the .h file. So why doesn't it work?

I use Code::Blocks, where i compile and run(no command lines), in Windows 7. I do suspect that something isn't set up quite right, however, I do want to know for sure if it is my code that fails.

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.h"  //This don't work. If i include Foo.cpp it does. 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Foo k(10);
    cout << k.getInt() << endl;
}
```

foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(int tall);
        int getInt()const;
    protected:
    private:
        int m;
};

#endif
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo(int tall)
: m(tall)
{
    //ctor
}

int Foo::getInt()const
{
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Probably best to pick up a book and start getting familiar with the basics! 1) your program doesn't generate an error, your compiler does. 2) it's not a compile error but a linker error. 3) you don't "import" the header file, you *include* it. 4) learn about translation units, modular compilation and linking.

Comment: Ok, I realize I did write this post a little too fast. I did know that it was the compiler which generated the error, I could guess the second point (not so familiar with linking yet), and the third one was just a mistype - my first language was Java. The fourth point does seem like a good idea, though.
Thanks.

Comment: @MartinHaTh: The crucial difference is that Java's `import` really *imports* the module and locates all the relevant files for you, while in C++ all you do is literally *include* the content of the file, which is only a *header* file -- you still need to perform the linking yourself. So the difference in nomenclature is more than apt.

Comment: It's pretty safe to say never `#include` .cpp files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile both *main.cpp* and *foo.cpp* and link the 2 resulting object files together.

Comment: I guess Code::Blocks should do it automatically

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato I just googled Code::Blocks and it seems the IDE is supposed to take care of all that. Maybe the OP created an empty project so the wizard didn't create any settings.

Comment: Well, I guess it could be my fault. I created a blank file(just to not get the .h file), and named it Main.cpp. Then, after writing the class, I created a new class, which created the cpp and header file. This might be the problem.

Ok, I can confirm that this was the problem. It's all working fine now. Man, I'm silly...

Comment: @MartinHaTh Create a project using Code::Blocks, add the 2 files to the project and the IDE should take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You are failing to compile and/or link the Foo.cpp file when you do your linking step.  I'm not familiar with Code::Blocks though, so I can't tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your .cpp file and go to properties. On build tab make sure compile, link, debug, and release are checked.

[image]

Comment: What OS is that? It looks like Debian

Comment: @Arc676 I think it was Arch with xfce.

Comment: Does Arch have a console interface? The Raspberry Pi OS "Raspbian" (version of Debian) boots into a console and requires a Terminal command to activate the GUI. I downloaded Debian but the only console interface it has is the recovery console. Does Arch have a similar interface?